# 3DS Max viewport canvas painting artifacts

Tags: 3ds-max

I created a cucumber model model (my first model) in 3DS Max 14. I used object paint to paint the bumps on the cucumber and user proboolean to attach the bumps to the cucumber.
i am working with the default international unit 
and the cucumber is about 4 in length (I want to work in a 1:1 scale with a game engine).
After all the modifiers i flattened the model out and it is just an editable poly.
when I start to paint it looks like this:
[image: cucumber 1]

When i just move the paint brush over some weird areas (they are all highlighted), I get wierd painting all over the cucumber:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is it the scale? Is it the object paint? 
Also can someone tell me a quick (auto) way to make the intersection areas of the bumps quad friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to unwrap the UV's first to not overlap  (UVW unrwapp modifier).